# SQL query group by nearby timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a table with a timestamp column. I would like to be able to group by an identifier column (e.g. cusip), sum over another column (e.g. quantity), but only for rows that are within 30 seconds of each other, i.e. **not** in fixed 30 second bucket intervals. Given the data:

```
       cusip| quantity|    timestamp
============|=========|=============
BE0000310194|      100| 16:20:49.000
BE0000314238|       50| 16:38:38.110
BE0000314238|       50| 16:46:21.323
BE0000314238|       50| 16:46:35.323
```

I would like to write a query that returns:

```
       cusip| quantity
============|=========
BE0000310194|      100
BE0000314238|       50
BE0000314238|      100
```

Edit:
In addition, it would greatly simplify things if I could also get the MIN(timestamp) out of the query.

Comment: Consider the values 1:01, 1:22, 1:45. The first and last values are both within 30 seconds of the middle value but not within 30 seconds of each other. How many groups is this? One - they all get grouped together (but then the outer values aren't within 30 seconds of each other)? Two - the middle value groups with both the outer values as it is within 30 seconds of both (and hence is counted twice)?

Comment: In practice, variant one will always be true.

Comment: What is your logic to find out first timestamp group?

Comment: Which of these statements is true? (a) Rows are grouped when the timestamp is no more than 30 seconds later than the MINIMUM timestamp in the group (that is, the group can span at most 30 seconds); or (b) Rows are grouped when the timestamp is no more than 30 seconds later than the PREVIOUS timestamp in the group (that is, the group consists of as many rows as occur in quick succession after each other even though that may span well over 30 seconds)

Comment: Chris, this looks to me like a re-phrasing of your first question, and the answer is still the same, in practice, a group will span at most 30 seconds from start to finish. It will really only be a few seconds in the vast majority of the cases. But honestly, I think I could make either variant work. Do you have a pure SQL solution for either? Right now I have to resort to getting all entries, and manipulating in perl to do the grouping procedurally.

Answer (score 2):

From Sean G solution, I have removed Group By on complete Table. In Fact re adjected few parts for Oracle SQL.

First after finding previous time, assign self parent id. If there a null in Previous Time, then we exclude giving it an ID.

Now based on take the nearest self parent id by avoiding nulls so that all nearest 30 seconds cusip fall under one Group.

As There is a CUSIP column, I assumed the dataset would be large market transactional data. Instead using group by on complete table, use partition by CUSIP and final Group Parent ID for better performance.

```
SELECT
id,
sub.parent_id,
sub.cusip,
timestamp,
quantity,
sum(sub.quantity) OVER(
    PARTITION BY cusip, parent_id
) sum_quantity,
MIN(sub.timestamp) OVER(
    PARTITION BY cusip, parent_id
) min_timestamp
FROM
(
    SELECT
        base_sub.*,
        CASE
            WHEN base_sub.self_parent_id IS NOT NULL THEN
                base_sub.self_parent_id
            ELSE
                LAG(base_sub.self_parent_id) IGNORE NULLS OVER(
                    PARTITION BY cusip
                    ORDER BY
                        timestamp, id
                )
        END parent_id
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                c.*,
                CASE
                    WHEN nvl(abs(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM to_timestamp(previous_timestamp, 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') - to_timestamp
                    (timestamp, 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'))), 31) > 30 THEN
                        id
                    ELSE
                        NULL
                END self_parent_id
            FROM
                (
                    SELECT
                        my_table.id,
                        my_table.cusip,
                        my_table.timestamp,
                        my_table.quantity,
                        LAG(my_table.timestamp) OVER(
                            PARTITION BY my_table.cusip
                            ORDER BY
                                my_table.timestamp, my_table.id
                        ) previous_timestamp
                    FROM
                        my_table
                ) c
        ) base_sub
) sub
```

Below are the Table Rows

Input Data:

[image: Input Data]

Below is the Output

RESULT

[image: RESULT]

Comment: I know you wrote this solution nearly 3 years ago but ty.

Answer (score 0):

Following may be helpful to you.

Grouping of 30 second periods stating form a given time. Here it is '2012-01-01 00:00:00'. DATEDIFF counts the number of seconds between time stamp value and stating time. Then its is divided by 30 to get grouping column.

```
SELECT MIN(TimeColumn) AS TimeGroup, SUM(Quantity) AS TotalQuantity FROM YourTable
GROUP BY (DATEDIFF(ss, TimeColumn, '2012-01-01') / 30)
```

Here minimum time stamp of each group will output as TimeGroup. But you can use maximum or even grouping column value can be converted to time again for display.

Comment: This will not work due the the "not 30 second bucket intervals" I mentioned in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the above comments, I'm assuming Chris's first scenario is the one you want (all 3 get grouped even though values 1 and 3 are not within 30 seconds of eachother, but are each within 30 seconds of value 2). Also going to assume that each row in your table has some unique ID called 'id'. You can do the following:

1. Create a new grouping, determining if the preceding row in your partition is more than 30 seconds behind the current row (e.g. determine if you need a new 30 second grouping, or to continue the previous). We'll call that parent_id.
2. Sum quantity over parent_id (plus any other aggregations)

The code could look like this

```
select
    sub.parent_id,
    sub.cusip,
    min(sub.timestamp) min_timestamp,
    sum(sub.quantity) quantity
from 
    (
        select
            base_sub.*,
            case
                when base_sub.self_parent_id is not null
                then base_sub.self_parent_id
                else lag(base_sub.self_parent_id) ignore nulls over (
                    partition by
                        my_table.cusip
                    order by
                        my_table.timestamp,
                        my_table.id
                    ) parent_id
        from 
            (
                select
                    my_table.id,
                    my_table.cusip,
                    my_table.timestamp,
                    my_table.quantity,
                    lag(my_table.timestamp) over (
                        partition by
                            my_table.cusip
                        order by
                            my_table.timestamp,
                            my_table.id
                        ) previous_timestamp,
                    case
                        when datediff(
                            second, 
                            nvl(previous_timestamp, to_date('1900/01/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd')),
                            my_table.timestamp) > 30
                        then my_table.id
                        else null
                    end self_parent_id
                from
                    my_table
            ) base_sub
    ) sub
group by
    sub.time_group_parent_id,
    sub.cusip
```